# Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed

Tags: c#, https, httpwebrequest

I'm interfacing the Skyview site (https://skyview.gsfc.nasa.gov/current/cgi/basicform.pl) for retrieving astronomic plates (i.e. images).

I build the URL with the necessary parameters and create a HttpWebRequest:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
```

Since it is *https* I previously inserted these lines, as I saw in another thread here in SO:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

I then read the site answer in this way:

```
            List<string> resp = new List<string>();

            const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1000;
            {
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        int bytesRead;
                        do
                        {
                            var buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                            bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                            resp.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
                        } while (bytesRead > 0);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Once the site has answered:

- I parse the result (resp)
- find for the plate filename in it
- do another request to get it

Everything works fine if the plate size is not big: the site takes just few minutes (less than 5) to produce the plate file and I can get it correctly.

When I specify bigger fields, Skyview needs more time to fetch the image and send me back the file URL and, after around 300s, I get this error:

**Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed**

If I do it via browser, it works. I tested with a quite big image and it took 21 minutes without getting any error.

I went through some solutions here in SO but they seem not to work for my case.

Comment: Searching for "HttpWebRequest 300s" brings up [`HttpWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.readwritetimeout?view=netframework-4.8). You probably need to set that a bit higher.

Comment: This is one of the solutions I tried, I set it to 1800000ms (half a hour)

                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                    request.Timeout = 1000 * 60 * 30;
                    request.ReadWriteTimeout = 1000 * 60 * 30;

Comment: And then what happened? Was it exactly the same exception after exactly 300s, or did the problem change slightly?

Comment: Same exception. If you'd like to try here it follows the URL for a quite big plate that raises the exception: https://skyview.gsfc.nasa.gov/current/cgi/runquery.pl?Position=NGC7000&survey=DSS2+Red&coordinates=J2000&coordinates=&projection=Tan&pixels=600&size=15&float=on&scaling=Log&resolver=SIMBAD-NED&Sampler=_skip_&Deedger=_skip_&rotation=&Smooth=&lut=colortables%2Fb-w-linear.bin&PlotColor=&grid=_skip_&gridlabels=1&catalogurl=&CatalogIDs=on&survey=_skip_&survey=_skip_&survey=_skip_&IOSmooth=&contour=&contourSmooth=&ebins=null

Comment: Same exception *after exactly 300s*?

Comment: I'm not going to max out my work's internet connection for 5 minutes to test this I'm afraid

Comment: Around 300s, yes

Comment: I would download the data in xml which is much easier to parse.  See the user guide : https://skyview.gsfc.nasa.gov/current/docs/skyviewinajar.html

Comment: Anyway, I made some further tests and the timeout seems to appear in this line: 
bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

It seems like after exactly 300s the Read exits with 0 bytes read